# I would like to create a task dependsOn assembleRelease in gradle, AS, but the task alse dependsOn the assembleDebug.

Tags: android, gradle, task

The `VersionName` of an application is like 'major.minor.patch'. I need to add the patch number automatically every time the .apk was assembled. For example, let's assume the VersionName is  '1.0.1', after I execute `gradlew assemble` or `gradlew assembleRelease`, I want the VersionName change to '1.0.2'.

So, I make a `version.properties` file in the /app.

```
major=1
minor=0
patch=1
```

And part of the build.gradle in /app is as following:

```
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled = true
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-debug'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
                    def newName = variant.name + "_" + getCustomVersionName() + "_" + releaseTime + ".apk"
                    outputFileName = new File(newName)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

finally, I define a custom task depends on the *assembleRelease* task.

```
   task addVersionCode(dependsOn: 'assembleRelease') {
     Properties versionProperties = new Properties()
     versionProperties.load(project.file('version.properties').newInputStream())
     def customNum = versionProperties.getProperty('custom')
     versionProperties.setProperty('custom', ++customNum)
     versionProperties.save(project.file('version.properties').newOutputStream(), 'add version code')
}
```

it works. but every time I execute the `gradlew assembleDebug` in the termial. the `addVersionCode` task also execute and the `VersionName`(the patch in the version.properties file) also increase. I don not want this, I just want to execute the task when I execute `gradlew assembleRelease`, What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so stupid, the `addVersionCode` task should be a execution task rather than a configuration task. so just change the method of defining of a task and add `doLast`. Finally, `assembleRelease` task was add as a dependence. just like following:

```
Task autoChangeVersionCode = task(autoChangeVersionCode, group: BasePlugin.BUILD_GROUP)

autoChangeVersionCode.doLast {
    Properties versionProperties = new Properties()
    versionProperties.load(project.file('version.properties').newInputStream())
    def custom = versionProperties.getProperty('custom')
    versionProperties.setProperty('custom', ++custom)
    versionProperties.store(project.file('version.properties').newOutputStream(), 'increase version code')
}
```

It works for me.